# Создание матрицы преобразований

Tags: c#, математика, opengl, матрицы

Пишу свой движок на С#. Решил написать для него собственную библиотеку для работы с матрицами и векторами. Есть реализация векторов, сейчас делаю матрицы, но никак не могу сделать правильную матрицу преобразований. Основная проблема в том что при повороте объекта меняется и его размер.

```
using UrsaEngine.Math;
namespace UrsaEngine.Math
{
    public struct Matrix4x4
    {
        #region static
        public static Matrix4x4 Identity { get; } = new Matrix4x4(new float[,]
        {
            {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
            {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
            {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},
            {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}
        });
        public static Matrix4x4 Zero { get; } = new Matrix4x4(0);
        #endregion
        private float[,] matArr = new float[4, 4];

        public Matrix4x4() { }
        public Matrix4x4(Vector4 vec1, Vector4 vec2, Vector4 vec3, Vector4 vec4)
        {
            matArr[0, 0] = vec1.x;
            matArr[0, 1] = vec1.y;
            matArr[0, 2] = vec1.z;
            matArr[0, 3] = vec1.w;

            matArr[1, 0] = vec2.x;
            matArr[1, 1] = vec2.y;
            matArr[1, 2] = vec2.z;
            matArr[1, 3] = vec2.w;

            matArr[2, 0] = vec3.x;
            matArr[2, 1] = vec3.y;
            matArr[2, 2] = vec3.z;
            matArr[2, 3] = vec3.w;

            matArr[3, 0] = vec4.x;
            matArr[3, 1] = vec4.y;
            matArr[3, 2] = vec4.z;
            matArr[3, 3] = vec4.w;
        }
        public Matrix4x4(int value)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
            {
                for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++)
                {
                    matArr[r, c] = value;
                }
            }
        }
        public Matrix4x4(float[,] arr)
        {
            matArr = arr;
        }
        #region Data Access
        public float this[int row, int col]
        {
            get
            {
                return matArr[row, col];
            }
            set
            {
                matArr[row, col] = value;
            }
        }
        public Vector4 GetRowV(int row)
            => new Vector4(matArr[0, row], matArr[1, row], matArr[2, row], matArr[3, row]);
        public Vector4 GetColV(int col)
            => new Vector4(matArr[0, col], matArr[1, col], matArr[2, col], matArr[3, col]);
        public float[] GetRow(int row)
            => new float[] { matArr[row, 0], matArr[row, 1], matArr[row, 2], matArr[row, 3] };
        public float[] GetCol(int col)
            => new float[] { matArr[0, col], matArr[1, col], matArr[2, col], matArr[3, col]};

#endregion
        #region Transformations
        public static Matrix4x4 Scale(Vector3 scale)
        {
            Matrix4x4 result = Matrix4x4.Identity;
            result[0, 0] = scale.x;
            result[1, 1] = scale.y;
            result[2, 2] = scale.z;
            return result;
        }
        public static Matrix4x4 Translate(Vector3 translation)
        {
            Matrix4x4 result = Matrix4x4.Identity;
            result[0, 3] = translation.x;
            result[1, 3] = translation.y;
            result[2, 3] = translation.z;
            return result;
        }
        public static Matrix4x4 Rotate(Vector3 axis, float angle)
        {
            angle = UMathF.Radians(angle);
            float x = axis.x;
            float y = axis.y;
            float z = axis.z;
            float cA = MathF.Cos(angle);
            float sA = MathF.Sin(angle);

            float m00 = cA + (x * x) * (1 - cA);
            float m10 = y * x * (1 - cA) + z * sA;
            float m20 = z * x * (1 - cA) - y * sA;

            float m01 = x * y * (1 - cA) - z * sA;
            float m11 = cA + (y * y) * (1 - cA);
            float m21 = z * y * (1 - cA) + x * sA;

            float m02 = x * z * (1 - cA) + y * sA;
            float m12 = y * z * (1 - cA) - x * sA;
            float m22 = cA + (z * z) * (1 - cA);
            Matrix4x4 mat = Matrix4x4.Identity;
            mat[0, 0] = m00;
            mat[1, 0] = m10;
            mat[2, 0] = m20;

            mat[0, 1] = m01;
            mat[1, 1] = m11;
            mat[2, 1] = m21;

            mat[0, 2] = m02;
            mat[1, 2] = m12;
            mat[2, 2] = m22;
            return mat;
        }
        public static Matrix4x4 TRS(Vector3 scale, Vector3 rotation, float angle, Vector3 translation)
        {
            Matrix4x4 result = Matrix4x4.Identity;
            result *= Scale(scale);
            result *= Rotate(rotation, angle);
            result *= Translate(translation);

            return result;
        }
        #endregion
        #region Math operations
        public static Matrix4x4 operator *(Matrix4x4 left, Matrix4x4 right)
        {
            float[,] res = new float[4, 4];
            for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
            {
                for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++)
                {
                    res[r, c] = left[r, 0] * right[0, c] + left[r, 1] * right[1, c] + left[r, 2] * right[2, c] + left[r, 3] * right[3, c];
                }
            }
            return new Matrix4x4(res);
        }
        public static Matrix4x4 operator *(Matrix4x4 left, float number)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
                {
                    left[r, c] *= number;
                }
            }
            return left;
        }
        public static Vector4 operator *(Matrix4x4 left, Vector4 right)
        {
            Vector4 result = new Vector4();
            result[0] = left[0, 0] * right[0] + left[0, 1] * right[0] + left[0, 2] * right[0] + left[0, 3] * right[0];
            result[1] = left[1, 0] * right[0] + left[1, 1] * right[0] + left[1, 2] * right[0] + left[1, 3] * right[0];
            result[2] = left[2, 0] * right[0] + left[2, 1] * right[0] + left[2, 2] * right[0] + left[2, 3] * right[0];
            result[3] = left[3, 0] * right[0] + left[3, 1] * right[0] + left[3, 2] * right[0] + left[3, 3] * right[0];
            return result;
        }
        public static Matrix4x4 operator +(Matrix4x4 left, Matrix4x4 right)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
                {
                    left[r, c] += right[r, c];
                }
            }
            return left;
        }
        public static Matrix4x4 operator -(Matrix4x4 left, Matrix4x4 right)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
                {
                    left[r, c] -= right[r, c];
                }
            }
            return left;
        }
        #endregion
     
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137035/discussion-on-question-by-deril---).